# Bigquery - Where clause - Dynamically get 1st of previous month

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date field that has been set as a string (Unfortunately i cannot change this) which appears as '2016-02-01'

I want to write a query that i can use a where clause to always select the previous month.

The data is always set to the 1st of a month if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT d as m, DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(d) , -1, 'MONTH')) as prev_m
FROM 
  (SELECT '2016-01-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-02-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-03-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-04-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-05-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-06-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-07-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-08-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-09-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-10-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-11-01' AS d),
  (SELECT '2016-12-01' AS d)
```

> Added for WHERE clause

(I realised below is most likely what you asked)

```
WHERE YEAR(d) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, 'MONTH')) 
AND MONTH(d) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -1, 'MONTH'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mikhail Berlyant's answer (`date(date_add(timestamp(d),-1,'month'))`), you could consider building a table that has the current month in one column and the previous month in another. Depending on your needs, this table could also include columns that correspond to six months ago, one year ago, etc. You then join on that table.